# Ampscript loops to print from second data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using two data extensions, with a primary key in both as Id, first data extension contacts fields as name, email, brand, id.  second one contains id, brand, delivers. One name can have more than one delivers. So how to print that? I am getting only one delivers output.

```
%%[
 VAR @Id,@Delivers
]%%

Hi %%Name%% <br>

Thanks for showing your interest in our Brand.<br>

Brand = %%Brand%%<br>

The brand you have showed interest in will help you to serve in the below area:
<br/>

%%[

 SET @Id = AttributeValue("Id")
 SET @Delivers = Lookup('Brandonetomany','Delivers','Id', @Id)

]%%

%%=v(@Delivers)=%% <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started:

```
%%[
VAR @myrowset,
@rowCount,
@row,
@i,
@delivery
SET @id = Lookup("myFirstDE","id","id",_subscriberkey)
/*return from myFirstDE the field id, where id == _subscriberkey"*/

SET @myrowset = LookupRows("mysecondDE","Id",@id)
SET @rowCount = rowcount(@myrowset)

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO

    SET @row = row(@myrowset,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
    SET @delivery = field(@row,"delivery")
]%%
Deliverynumber and value : %%v=(@i)=%%, %%=v(@delivery)=%% <br>
%%[

NEXT @i

ENDIF
]%%
```